# What is the probability distribution of a web-server receiving a client connection request?

Tags: distributions

An internet search for the probability distribution of a server getting a connection yielded no relevant results.

My guess is it would be be poisson or normal distribution, but I need something a bit better than a guess, so please cite a source for your answer!

Comment: Welcome to CV. It's not immediately apparent to me what you are asking. Would you please elaborate on what a "server getting a connection" is about and/or means -- in non-IT terms?

Comment: Basically it means that some remote machine is attempting to contact the server (to ask for data or to submit it).

Comment: So, it can be high frequency count data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to have one answer for all circumstances.

When looking at the number of requests as a function of number of websites, you are hiding a third latent variable, which is the website type.

There are websites that do not attract any kind of user engagement (e.g. "about us" pages)  and there are websites that attract a lot of user engagement (e.g. Facebook and cross-validate (: )

The Poisson distribution assumes a memory-less behavior, this could be a good model if each web request for the website is single, and independent of each-other.

For example, I would expect that the wallmart's opening hours page would have this behavior.

But looking at an eCommerce websites (e.g. eBay, Amazon) , the behavior is much more complex, just imagine how does a black Friday would affects the number of requests.

In addition I would expect to see an underlying distribution of user types, for example "bargain seekers","compulsive buyers","feedback oriented" that would generate the observed "request distribution" in question.

To sum up, I doubt that you would find a "silver bullet" distribution for all website's request count. There are a lot of factors that depend on the website type and the user it attracts that need to be accounted for